# Chrome shows 'aw, snap' page and puts a breakpoint on last line

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have an issue with Chrome.
When the dev tools on Chrome are closed the webpage is loading perfectly, but, when I open the dev tools and refresh the page it shows the 'Aw, snap' page and places a breakpoint on the last line of code.
What may be the cause for this?
Chrome version is 26.0.1410.63.
Thanks :)

Comment: It sounds like you're crashing Chrome itself.  You should submit a bug report.

Comment: There are a large number of things that will crash chrome that are not bugs.

Comment: But why isn't it crash when dev tools are closed?

Comment: Try reducing your webpage to see exactly what causes it to crash. Because I'm assuming it's only your website that this is happening on.
We can't really see why it's crashing if we can't look at the website.

Comment: It's not consistent.. When it happens I can open a new tab with the same page and it doesn't happen there, but continue to happen on the previous tab..
Is there any log where I can see what causes the page to crash or something?

Comment: Check here: http://superuser.com/questions/607563/how-to-determine-what-is-causing-chrome-to-show-the-aw-snap-dialogue

I don't know if that will help, but it should show the logs as to why it happened.